# Servidor responde 404 solo con archivos csv muy pesados enviados desde angularjs

Tags: java, angular, angularjs

Buen día.

Tengo una aplicación realizada en AngularJS y como backend Java en la cual cargo un archivo .csv y lo envio al backend, todo funciona muy bien con archivos csv pequeños pero ahora que estoy probando con archivos pesados me doy cuenta que el servicio en java ni siquiera se ejecuta ya que no se escriben los logs

Dejo el código del cliente donde envio los datos del form:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('csvFileInput');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var fileName = fileInput.files[0].name;
    
    if (file) {
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('csvFile', file)
      formData.append('fileName', fileName)

      $http.post('/services/rest/afiliado/cargueBloqueoAfiliados', formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
      }).then(function(data) {
        // Manejar la respuesta del servidor aquí
        console.log(data.data);
        if(data.data.codRespuesta == '18' ||  data.data.codRespuesta=='22' || data.data.codRespuesta=='23' || data.data.codRespuesta=='24' || data.data.codRespuesta=='25' || data.data.codRespuesta=='26'){
            
            //Se filtra el mensaje a mostrar
            $scope.resp=filterFilter($scope.mensajes,data.data.codRespuesta);
            //Se carga el titulo del mensaje y el contenido del mismo.
            $scope.mensaje=$scope.resp[0].descripcion;
            // $scope.observacion=$scope.resp[0].observacion;
            //Se muestra el mensaje
            alert($scope.mensaje);
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Manejar errores en la solicitud al servidor
        console.error(error);
      });
    }else{
        console.log("No Existe")
    }
```

Ahora la firma de servicio en Java:

```
@POST
@Path("/cargueBloqueoAfiliados")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public Respuesta cargueBloqueoAfiliados(
        @Context HttpHeaders headers, 
        @Context HttpServletRequest requestContext,
        MultipartFormDataInput fileDetalle
        ) throws Exception {
```

Esta es la respuesta en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro tener un indicio de por que no se ejecuta el servicio al ser llamado por el cliente, lo que he notado desde el inspector del navegador es que hay unos segundos de espera desde el momento se hace el llamado al servicio hata que se obtiene la respuesta 404.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría que primero comprobaras sólo el backend. Por ejemplo usando RestClient(extensión de VSCode). Eso te permitirá saber si es del back o del front el problema, y una vez solucionado el back te vas a la parte AngularJs.